# How to print the last column of a row only using "grep" and "cut" bash command

Tags: bash, grep, cut

I need to parse the line written bold below:

```
line="eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 11:11:11:11:11:11"
```

This line may have more words unexpectedly such as

```
line="eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  Extra HWaddr 11:11:11:11:11:11"
```

So, for parsing the MAC address correctly, I need to parse the line accordingly with a bash command.

`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f5*` works for the first line, while `*echo $line | cut -d' ' -f6*` works for the second. So, I need to parse only the last column of the line.

However, because of the device restriction, I can only use **grep** and **cut** command. Not **sed**, **awk**, **rev**,**reverse**, etc.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Last column with awk: `awk '{print $NF}'`

Comment: Somebody has added double asterisks to the `line`. Did you mean that the `*` characters were supposed to be included into the string, or you just wanted to emphasize it as **bold**?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: I think it came from the previous edit than mine, looking at this edit history, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40760215/revisions

Comment: @Inian , The line is edited which are with no stars. Expected output is  11:11:11:11:11:11

Comment: Also, the command will be executed in a telnet session.

Answer (score 3):

With `grep`:

```
echo $line | grep -o -E '[^ ]+$'
```

With `cut`, a solution can be made with an extra computation based on the word count, assuming the delimiter is a space:

```
nw=$(echo $line | wc -w)
echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f$nw-
```

Answer (score 1):

If the MAC address is the last sequence of characters after a space, you can remove the longest match of `"* "` (asterisk and a space) pattern using pure Bash:

```
echo "${line##* }"
```

You can also extract the last 17 characters from the string:

```
echo "${line: -17}"
```

If you want a strict match at the *end* of the line (due to `.*`):

```
echo $(expr match "$line" '.*\(\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2\}\:\)\{5\}[a-zA-Z0-9]\{2\}\)')
```

Using GNU `grep`:

```
grep -o -P '(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}:){5}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}' <<< "$line"
```

In the latter case, you may want to add the `$` anchor for the end of the line. Of course, you don't have to use here string. You may want to use a *pipe* instead: `echo "$line" | grep -o -P ...`.